# See a list of recently accessed files, sorted by date

Tags: unity

In Ubuntu, is it possible to view a list of all recently accessed files (by date?) The Unity search menu only shows a short list of recent files for a given search term: I'd like to see a longer list of recent files.

I think I once encountered a program that may have done something like this - I think it was an add-on for Gnome Do, but I can't remember its name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [GNOME Activity Journal](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnome-activity-journal) should list your recent files in a nice way.

Comment: Does this show files that were viewed, or does it only show files that were modified?